# Why is URL_Launcher for Flutter not working?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app, and I need hyperlinks in it, such as some text saying "Tap me", and when you tap it it takes you to a pre-specified link. Sounded simple, so I looked online and everyone says to use the `url_launcher` package, however this doesn't work for me. I tried all I could and it still doesn't work.

Here is my issue: I followed all of the installation steps, yet when I try to run my app from scratch, it gives me this error: `CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state. Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.` I found that when I deleted the `url_launcher` from my pubspec.yaml, and all references to it from my code, this error suddenly goes away and the app runs perfectly fine. I have not found anyone else encounter this error, so any help is greatly appreciated. If it's not fixable, is there any good alternative to `url_launcher`?

Comment: did you run `pod install` in your ios folder? And did you run `pub get` from your root folder?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by running 'pod install' in my iOS folder. But CocoaPods is not the problem, it''s the fact that url_launcher messes up everything.

Comment: @SpicyPumpkin Please try the suggested solution first before making further questions. Also, it's not clear what you meant by "url_launcher messed up everything". The problem is not on the package, but the way you're setting up it.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I've already specified in the original post what the url_launcher messes up. Secondly, the above solution does not work, and is not clear. 'pod install' is not a command the Flutter terminal recognizes. I have also set it up exactly as shown in the Flutter docs, at least I believe so, and it is still not working; that is why I decided to make a post and ask about it.

Comment: @SpicyPumpkin That's exactly the part where you're missing. There's no way you've been developing on iOS and have never used the `pod command` yet. You can see on the [Build and release an iOS app](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios), the `pod install` command is being used there.